# VBA custom IF function not working

Tags: excel, vba

I had the following IF statement:

```
lF(C:C=CE,0.3,(IF(C:C=CS,0.2,(IF( C:C=TE,0.2,(IF( C:C=MV,0.25,(IF( C:C=HCV,0.375,(IF( C:C=HM,0.3,(IF( C:CLM,0.125,(IF( C:C=FF,0.125,(IF( C:C=OE,0.3,0))))))))))
```

Which I then entered as a function in my first VBA module as:

```
Function DepRate(pVal As String) As Long

   If pVal = "HCV" Then
      DepRate = 0.375

   ElseIf pVal = "OE" Then
      DepRate = 0.3

   ElseIf pVal = "CE" Then
      DepRate = 0.3

   ElseIf pVal = "CS" Then
      DepRate = 0.2

   ElseIf pVal = "TE" Then
      DepRate = 0.2

   ElseIf pVal = "MV" Then
      DepRate = 0.25

   ElseIf pVal = "FF" Then
      DepRate = 0.125

   ElseIf pVal = "LM" Then
      DepRate = 0.125

   Else
      DepRate = 0
   End If

End Function
```

The result, when the function is used on excel, is always 0 even when the value in the particular cell is true.

How to correct this?

Comment: What value do you pass to the function and how?

Comment: Is this an array formula in the worksheet as it appears to be acting on an entire column of cells. Also - I'm not sure what `CE`, `CS` are... They are not strings as otherwise they would be enclosed in `""`. Are they named ranges in your workbook?

Comment: Thanks El. I selected Case and also excluded the "As Long" command as it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is a formula which refers to named ranges. So for example `C:C = CE` is comparing values in the column C to the named range `CE`.

So for example you need to have a function like this...

```
Function DepRate(pVal As String) As Long

   If pVal = ActiveSheet.Range("HCV").Value Then
      DepRate = 0.375
etc... etc..
```

You could also use a Select..Case as Veve says. But perhaps even better would be hold the values in a hidden sheet and then the lookups can be more easily configured.

I would be interested know what is in the named range `CE` for example? (Formulas > Name manager)

Comment: Thanks. I selected Case and also excluded the "As Long" command as it was unnecessary.It functioned well but I have yet to find a way to ensure that the function still works when I open the sheet in future without having to import it each time. I might just work back and create a simpler IF statement. Yes 'CE' was a value in the cells in the column C:C . Its was a result of a v-look up to quantify the variables in cells in columns A:A and B:B.

Comment: Yes, `Long` is not appropriate for the function anyway as it is returning non-integer values. `As Single` or `As Double` should be used instead - I didn't notice this before. What do you say you are having to "import each time"?